# Can't Close Window

Tags: c++, c, sdl

I'm following the Lazy Foo tutorial on C++ and SDL2. I'm trying to learn it using regular C and noticed something interesting when following instructions on adding events to detect a close window event.

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

bool init();
bool loadMedia();
void close();

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;

SDL_Window *gWindow = NULL;
SDL_Surface *gScreenSurface = NULL;
SDL_Surface *gHelloWorld = NULL;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(!init()) {
        printf("Failed to initialize!\n");
    }
    else {
        if(!loadMedia()) {
            printf("Failed to load media!\n");
        }
        else {
            bool quit = false;
            SDL_Event e;

            while(!quit) {
                printf("%d", SDL_PollEvent(&e));

                while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
                    if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                        quit = true;
                    }
                }   

                SDL_BlitSurface(gHelloWorld, NULL, gScreenSurface, NULL);
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(gWindow);
            }
        }
    }       

    close();

    return 0;
}

bool init()
{
    bool success = true;

    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        printf("SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    } 
    else {
        gWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL Tutorial 03", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

        if(gWindow == NULL) {
            printf("Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
            success = false;
        } 
        else {
            gScreenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(gWindow);
        }
    }

    return success;
}

bool loadMedia()
{
    bool success = true;

    gHelloWorld = SDL_LoadBMP("images/hello_world.bmp");

    if(gHelloWorld == NULL) {
        printf("Unable to load image %s! SDL_Error: %s\n", "images/hello_world.bmp", SDL_GetError());
        success = false;
    }

    return success;
}

void close()
{
    SDL_FreeSurface(gHelloWorld);
    gHelloWorld = NULL;

    SDL_DestroyWindow(gWindow);
    gWindow = NULL;

    SDL_Quit();
}
```

If I compile this with a ".c" extension, it compiles without errors, but selecting the "X" on the window title bar does nothing. If I change said extension to ".cpp", the "X" works as intended.

I'm using the following command to compile the code.

```
gcc main.c -w -lSDL2 -o main
```

Any ideas why this may work with C++, but not with C?

Comment: would it be a scope problem with `close()` call? can you check the warnings (instead of ignoring them with `-w`)? I bet they're mentionning `close` in the C command line.

Comment: `I told the compiler not to tell me if stuff was broken (-w), can anyone tell me why stuff is broken?`

Comment: Sorry, this was the command that tutorial advised to use. If I remove the "-w", I get no additional errors.

Comment: Put in `-Wall -Wextra` (all reasonable warnings) for good measure.

Comment: After adding both arguments, I get two warnings stating that my argc and *argv[] parameters are unused, which is true, but shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Without additional information, I would try to declare `quit` as a `volatile` variable.

Comment: I find that if I put "printf("%d", SDL_PollEvent(&e));" in the main while loop, it always equals zero, even after clicking the "X", therefor it should never start a iteration through the next while loop (unless it happens so fast, it doesn't output to the terminal).

Comment: Unfortunately declaring the "quit" variable as volatile didn't change the outcome. I posted the entirety of the code for review.

Comment: @azurepancake Your first call to `SDL_PollEvent(...)` remove an event and discard it. If you want to debug your code by printing the return value of this function, you have to store its return value in a temporary variable, print it and update it in your second loop.

Comment: Why do expect the same code to work in two different languages?

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte: Nonsense. `quit` cannot even be reached from outside its direct scope.

Comment: Event problem covered by an answer. C/C++ problem caused by `close` function overriding libc `close`, which SDL indirectly calls during window creation. C++ mangles funtion name so it doesn't alias (yet). Either rename function or make it `static`.

Comment: Thanks, yes that was the issue. I simply re-named that function.

Answer (score 3):

The function SDL_PollEvent will remove the event from the internal event queue if an address of an SDL_event object is passed to it.

The printf call, that also calls the function SDL_PollEvent, before the event loop which will remove the quit event from the queue. This means the event loop won't find this event:

```
printf("%d", SDL_PollEvent(&e));

while(SDL_PollEvent(&e) != 0) {
    if(e.type == SDL_QUIT) {
        quit = true;
    }
}
```

If you only want to check if there are events pending in the queue, then use the function SDL_PollEvent with a NULL argument:

```
printf("%d", SDL_PollEvent(NULL));
```