# SDL2 window opens and remains unresponsive

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I am unable to get my head around this. Have not had a chance to try this on another PC yet.

I have a very simple following code that opens a SDL window and enters a loop.
It opens the window and I am able to see that the loop does something, for example I tested with SDL_SetWindowtitle() using a incremental value and saw it growing so there is some life.

However it just remains stuck, unresponsive. I can not press close button or move the window. There are periods when it get little life and it "updates" but it goes back to being unresponsive again.

I am starting to think there is some stupid mistake in my code which I am just not noticing.

Code compiles all ok, with zero warnings or errors.
I am using MinGW 64 bit compiler on Windows 10 64 bits.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  SDL_Window *window;
  SDL_Surface *surface;
  SDL_Renderer *renderer;
  SDL_Event event;

  int WINDOW_WIDTH = 1280;
  int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 720;
  bool exit = 1;

  if (SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0) {
    return 2;
  }

  window = SDL_CreateWindow("Gui test", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
  if (!window) {
    return 3;
  }

  surface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
  if (!surface) {
    return 4;
  }

  exit = false;
  while (!exit) {
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event) > 0) {

      switch(event.type) {
        case SDL_QUIT:
          exit = true;
          break;
      }

    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Delay(1000/30);
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

UPDATE: 
This seems to be a Windows specific issue. I noticed that after booting up my PC at work all thing work well for a while, but after a moment for some reason the issue returns. I have zero issues on Linux at home.

TLDR: Something is preventing SDL to work properly after a moment after computer boots up on Windows.

UPDATE2: 
Without any event handling the window is drawing perfectly fine. Tested with a simple renderer and background color change. BUT, as soon as I implement any event handling function (even SDL_PumpEvents(0)), the window freezes and it will take around 5-10 seconds till the background gets rendered. It seems to hang on event handling.

Comment: Have you tried moving `SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);` outside the event loop? That's the only thing that doesn't look right in your code at a glance.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, I tried that, but the result is the same. stil unrenponsive. Is there anything on OS level outside the program that could cause this? Would be odd though.

Comment: I'm not sure. Could you try with a debugger (or event `printf`s) to see if there's an SDL function that takes too much time to run?

Comment: Also, your code seems to be missing a closing bracket. Can you please add it?

Comment: I did some debugging with printf() and for some reason it hangs on SDL_PollEvent(&event). It seems like the program never returns from there once it enters that function. EDIT: It does return, but it is very, very slow.

Comment: @Mikko-PenttiEinariEronen take a look at https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4391 . Try SDL 2.0.8 just in case.

Comment: This code ran 100% fine for me, maybe you could try replacing the call to SDL_PollEvent() with SDL_PumpEvents() and see what he outcome is? SDL_PollEvent implicitly calls SDL_PumpEvents() but it might give you some more information. Good luck!

Comment: I updated the original post with further information. I have no issues on Linux, but at work on Windows 10 after booting computer up it works well for a few minutes/for a moment and then the issue comes back again. I am completely lost as to what could cause this. It seems something outside SDL is blocking the window from updating. Even if I take out the whole event polling part and just try to update/redraw the window it still is not responding, except every 5-10 seconds for a second and then goes back to being unresponsive. This cycle goes on and on. Process sits at 0% CPU usage.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to interact with the window, like move it or close it, without some sort of function in there to process the event queue. As for redrawing I guess you could still redraw to the window

Comment: Should still redraw the window and let me move it around?

Comment: I don't think so, without pumping the event queue in some way I don't think you can interact with the window like move it or close it. The documentation (https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents) says: "SDL_PumpEvents() gathers all the pending input information from devices and places it in the event queue. Without calls to SDL_PumpEvents() no events would ever be placed on the queue." So things like mouse move events or mouse click events never get put in the queue for processing if it isn't called. SDL_PollEvent implicitly calls SDL_PumpEvents which adds events to the event queue.

Comment: So the actual issue is probably in the event handling

Comment: I think (though I haven't tested) you can still draw to the window without pumping events, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Mikko-PenttiEinariEronen yeah I would think so.

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. It did not render anything but still saw std::cout output in console. So the window is stuck, but the loop works

Comment: I've set up windows with SDL before where I forgot to poll events or pump events and the window appeared to be locked up, like I couldn't move it or close it. Sounds like the sort of behavior you are getting is due to the event queue not being handled properly, though I couldn't find anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Here's something interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39562704/cant-close-window. This answer seems to suggest that you're actually removing the event from the event queue by calling SDL_PollEvent(&event). Try changing SDL_PollEvent(&event) to SDL_PollEvent(NULL). You won't be able to close the window anymore but it should stop the window from locking up.

Comment: I did some further testing (thank you for the tips). Before while() loop I put a simple test std::cout << "before" << std::endl; SDL_PollEvent(0); std::cout << "After" << std::endl; It gets stuck on the PollEvent and takes a looong time to reach the "After" part. Same with SDL_PollEvent(&event).

Comment: No problem, I'm not so confident on the last post I made, it looks like everyone is using SDL_PollEvent(&event) in this way and it worked fine for me so it's probably not the issue.

Comment: Also I did some even more testing. I create a renderer and change the background color to red with SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(); SDL_RenderClear(); SDL_RenderPresent(); In that order. Without any event handling, just the while(true) loop. It enters the loop and changes the background right away. BUT, if I add any event handling (even with SDL_PumpEvents()) it just freezes and will take around 5-10 seconds till the background gets changed to red. It really seems that something is blocking the event hadling now. Could anything outside the program be intefering this?